Specified data directory does not exist - but it does
Similar to this question, bitcoind does not recognize an existing directory, even if it does not contain spaces as was the problem mentioned.
bitcoin.conf
# Specify a non-default location to store blockchain and other data.
datadir=~/bitcoin

Terminal (Linux):
USR:~/bitcoin-27.1/bin$ ./bitcoind -daemon
Error: Error reading configuration file: specified data directory "~/bitcoin" does not exist.
USR:~/bitcoin-27.1/bin$ cd ~/bitcoin
USR:~/bitcoin$


I'm pretty sure Bitcoin Core does not expand ~ into the home directory path. Try providing the full path, you can get it with pwd.

Thanks. It worked

Default folder is in the user folder, but name of the folder is .bitcoin.
